# Was Arthur Weasley's car truly invisible?

Tags: harry-potter

Outside of invisibility cloaks, the only mention of invisibility that I can recall in the series is Arthur Weasley's Ford Angila. I find it suspect that he was able to make a car turn invisible, but, as far as I know, the series has no invisibility spell. This raises the question: Was his car truly invisible? Or was it something lesser like Disillusionment?

Comment: It had an "[invisibility booster](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Invisibility_Booster)". [Pottermore](https://pottermore.fandom.com/wiki/Invisibility_Booster) described it thusly; "*"Arthur Weasley adds an Invisibility Booster to the flying Ford Anglia, activated by a small silver button on the dashboard. **The Invisibility Booster makes the car temporarily invisible, allowing it to be flown without the risk of Muggles seeing it."***". Since it only works on Muggles, it's possibly a [Muggle Repelling Charm](https://pottermore.fandom.com/wiki/Muggle-Repelling_Charm) of some description.

Comment: It was Somebody Else's Problem.

Comment: There are other mentions of invisibility and "disillusionment" in canon, IIRC, but that isn't important. The question presumes that there are (known to us) hard limits on invisibility spells while simultaneously acknowledging evidence to the contrary. We simply aren't given enough information to categorize every possible way to hide or disguise something in the HPU, but must accept that things exist as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The car was fitted with an Invisibility Booster as explained by Arthur:

> "No one would see — this little button here is an Invisibility Booster I installed — that'd get us up in the air — then we fly above the clouds. We'd be there in ten minutes and no one would be any the wiser —"
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*</sub>

Later on in the chapter when Ron and Harry steal the car and get spotted it is because the Invisibility Booster is failing. If it didn't turn them completely invisible or if it had failed before the car would likely have been spotted previously. So it would seem, and from the description in the text below, that the Invisibility Booster is able to turn the Anglia completely invisible.

> Ron pressed a tiny silver button on the dashboard. The car around them vanished —
> and so did they. Harry could feel the seat vibrating beneath him, hear the engine, feel
> his hands on his knees and his glasses on his nose, but for all he could see, he had
> become a pair of eyeballs, floating a few feet above the ground in a dingy street full of
> parked cars.
>
> "Let's go," said Ron's voice from his right.
>
> And the ground and the dirty buildings on either side fell away, dropping out of sight as the car rose; in seconds, the whole of London lay, smoky and glittering, below them. Then there was a popping noise and the car, Harry, and Ron reappeared.
>
> "Uh-oh," said Ron, jabbing at the Invisibility Booster. "It's faulty —"
>
> Both of them pummelled it. The car vanished. Then it flickered back again.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*</sub>

Comment: So how many muggles had a complete fit when a car they saw parked on the side of the road simply vanished before their eyes?

Comment: How silly is it to build an "invisibility booster" that makes the car invisible to its own driver!

Comment: @PeterM: Not nearly as many as had a fit after seeing it hovering in midair, one assumes. This was not a very good plan to begin with, faulty invisibility booster or no.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed invisibility spells. In Chapter Twenty-Four of *Order of the Phoenix* we find the following, in reference to Fred and George Weasley's Headless Hats:

> “How do those hats work, then?” said Hermione, distracted from her homework and watching Fred and George. “I mean, obviously it’s some kind of Invisibility Spell, but it’s rather clever to have extended the field of invisibility beyond the boundaries of the charmed object. . . . I’d imagine the charm wouldn’t have a very long life though . . .”